# Memory - Available vs Free?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

I have Windows 7, with 8 GB ram.

Currently I see:

[image]

I read [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111122071507AACMa6n) that:

- `Total` is the amount of RAM installed on your computer, listed in megabytes (MB). (**✔ ok**).
- `Cached` refers to the amount of physical memory used recently for system resources. (**✔ ok**).
- `Available` is the total of standby and free memory from the Resource Monitor. (**✔ ok**).
- `Free` is the amount of memory that is currently unused or doesn't contain useful information (unlike cached files, which do contain useful information).(**? Huh**).

I don't understand the last part. Does it mean that a program might have a memory size of `Available+Free`? (Because 'Available' is available and since `Free` contains unneccesary info - it can release its blocks.)

**Question**
Am I right? How much (according to my picture) **total** memory is available for a new executing program?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Free ram is ram that hasn't been allocated yet. Programs that aren't using ram keep it allocated for later because it's faster to reuse already allocated ram than free ram and reallocate it later. If a new process needs memory but the amount of free ram is low, some of the available memory will be deallocated.

Comment: So I ask , what maximum size  ( according to my pic) a new process can take ?

Comment: 5525 megabytes. Once this runs out, Windows will use page memory (hard drive space), which is slower.

Comment: `AVAILABLE+FREE` ? so my assumption was correct?

Comment: Yes, but remember that processes can share memory.

Comment: Tobi - so why does MS confuse the users ? actually there are 5525 mb free.... the user dont give a sh** about free. if a process need memory - it WILL occupy `AVAILABLE+FREE`....so ?

Answer (score 16):

@Tobi Hahn's answer is incorrect. The correct answer should be either `Available` or `Cached+Free`

As suggested by [whs in sevenforums.com](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/114504-diff-between-available-free-physical-memory.html#post1168960), `Look into Resource Monitor > Memory tab. That gives you a better picture.`

Here's my number (with graph):
[image: Resource Monitor]

- `Hardware Reserved` : Used bye BIOS and drivers
- `In Use` : Ram your programs/OS are using
- `Modified` : Dirty memory, need to write to disk before use.
- `Standby` : Cached data and code
- `Free` : Free

Also,

- `Available` : including `Standby` and `Free`. => `Standby+Free`
- `Cached` : including `Standby` and `Modified` => `Standby+Modified`

So The answer should be `Standby+Free` => `Available`.

Note: If you want to include `Modified`, then it would be `Modified+Standby+Free` => `Cached+Free`.